# Calculating the Stationary Distribution of a Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am working on 2.27 from Resnick's "Adventures in Stochastic Processes".

The problem states,

If $\{X_n\}$ is Markov with stationary distribution $\pi$, transition matrix $P$ and state space $S$, show that $\{(X_n,X_{n+1}), n \geq 0)\}$ is Markov. Give its stationary distribution.

Showing that $\{Y_n = (X_n,X_{n+1}), n \geq 0)\}$ was straightforward but I wasn't able to come up with an approach to calculate $\pi_{Y}$. I think I managed to guess a stationary distribution and verified whether it satisfied,

$$\pi_Y(i_1,i_2) = \sum_{(x,y) \in S \times S} \pi_Y(x,y)\mathbb P \{(x,y) \to (i_1,i_2)\}$$
I guessed that $\pi_Y(i_1,i_2) = \pi(i_1)P(i_1,i_2)$ and it seems to satisfy the above criteria but I don't like this approach at all. Could some one please illustrate a nice method for this question.

Comment: Hint: If $(X_n)$ is at stationarity, what is the distribution of $Y_0$ already?

Comment: @Did Thanks for the hint. If $\{X_n\}$ has reach stationary state and then we start looking at distribution of $Y_0$ I can relate $\pi_Y(i_1,i_2) = \pi(i_1)P(i_1,i_2)$. However I'm still rather unclear on how this approach should be forwarded. I was thinking of creating the transition matrix for $Y_n$ but ordering the states is a mess in itself in that situation.

Comment: This explains how to *find* $\pi_Y$. Is your question actually how to *check* that $\pi_Y$ is stationary? 'Cause this is not difficult either but a different question...

Comment: No, it's on how to find $\pi_Y$. I typically find $\pi$ by either finding $\nu = \nu P$ and normalising or taking the limit of $P^n(i,j)$.

Comment: OK. And my first comment explains how to find $\pi_Y$ in the present case. Question solved, right?

Comment: @Did I think so but I'm still a bit fuzzy. I'll write it up as an answer by tonight.

Comment: @Did I've written it up. Sorry for the late post. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Did's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470921/calculating-the-stationary-distribution-of-a-markov-chain#comment2995273_1470921) hint,

Let us assume that ${X_n}$ starts off with it's stationary distribution $\pi$.

$$
\begin{split}
\implies \mathbb{P}\{X_0 = i\} &= \pi(i) \\
\implies \mathbb{P}\{Y_0 = (i,j)\} &= \mathbb{P}\{X_0 = i, X_1 = j\} \\
                   &= \mathbb{P}\{X_0 = i\}\mathbb{P}\{X_1 = j|_{X_0 = i}\}\\ 
                   &= \mathbb{P}\{X_0 = i\}\mathbb{P}_i\{X_1 = j\}\\
                   &= \pi(i)P(i,j)\\  
\end{split}
$$

Now we should examine $\mathbb{P}\{Y_1\}$. 
$$
\begin{split}
 \mathbb{P}\{Y_1\} &= \mathbb{P}\{Y_1|_{Y_0}\}\mathbb{P}\{Y_0\} \\
\implies \mathbb{P}\{Y_i = (x,y)\} &= \sum_i\mathbb{P}\{Y_1 = (x,y)|_{Y_0 =(i,x)}\}\mathbb{P}\{Y_0=(i,x)\} \\
                   &= \sum_i P(x,y)\pi(i)P(i,x) \\
                   &= P(x,y)\sum_i \pi(i)P(i,x) \\
                   &= P(x,y)\pi(x) \\
\mathbb{P}\{Y_i = (x,y)\} &= \pi(x)P(x,y)=\pi_Y(x,y)\\
\end{split}
$$

Therefore we can see that ${Y_n}$ is also stationary if ${X_n}$ is stationary and $\pi_Y$ is the stationary distribution.